# Problems with DlInk 655 Shareport setup

Tags: router, troubleshooting, home-networking

I'm trying to get network printing working on my Dlink 655 router and I have to install a separate utility for the printer to be shared.

I have installed the utility on the computer as instructed but the utility is suppose to detect the router and then the printer connected to it but it's not doing that.

Does any one have any ideas how I can get the SharePort utility to find my router?

Comment: I ended up taking the router back because this never ended up working

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the firmware for that router is permanently botched.  They keep releasing firmware updates for it, but never get it right.  These firmware updates introduce tons of other problems like connection resets, drops, and lockups.

This is a really, really, really bad model.  If you don't believe me, check their support forums.